# meaning of "Calmly and deliberately, she cut up his suits one by one."

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

In the [definition of "deliberately" in Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deliberately), the second meaning which is "slowly and carefully" has an example: Calmly and deliberately, she cut up his suits one by one.

I don't understand the meaning of "cut up" and "suits" in this example sentence.

Comment: This would have more gravitas if you said what you *thought* they might mean.

Comment: @Tim At first I thought correctly i.e. she made the cloths into pieces by scissors. But after that I doubted because doing this is very crazy.

Comment: She was crazy (mad, upset). Her husband had strayed. Why wouldn't she be?

Comment: If you look at the link in my question, the example is provided without any context about a husband or a wife. It's just the sentence I wrote in the title of my question. @Anton reply provided a story about a couple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example of a context for such thoughts, a wife who discovers that her respectable and successful businessman husband has been unfaithful to her might take revenge by spoiling his smart clothes, such his business suits (trousers, jacket and waistcoat). Here is a well-known example:

> LADY SARAH GRAHAM-MOON discovered her husband Sir Peter was having an
> affair before their divorce was finalised. They had been married for 27
> years.
>
> Enraged, she cut off the arms of 32 of his £1,000 Savile Row suits. She also
> threw five litres of white paint over his BMW, which was parked outside his
> new lover’s home.
>
> Lady Sarah, then 62, went back to their former marital home in East Garston,
> Berks.
>
> She promptly left 70 bottles of his vintage wine — some worth up to £300 — on
> his neighbours’ doorsteps with their pints of milk in 1992.
>
> Sir Peter reckoned the stunt cost him £35,000.
>
> [The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/archives/news/571960/how-to-exact-revenge/)

Your quotation may apply to similar circumstances. She cuts the suits into a number of separate pieces. She does so slowly and calmly. In doing so she destroys part of his public image, hurting his identity, attacking things that matter to him.

Comment: Answering this diminishes the propriety of the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *propriety* in the sense of "correct moral behaviour or actions" (Cambridge Dictionary)? Would you please explain your comments to both answers? They seem to me to be only your opinion, and as such to be inappropriate, unhelpful to anyone, and to run contrary to the site guidance.

Comment: Greybeard does a LMGTFY. You explain _why_ an enraged wife might shred her husband's formal attire. CGEL level may not be mandatory on ELU, but junior-school material is hardly appropriate on a site aimed at _linguists_ (and is unique on SE in that a site for more basic questions was added).

Comment: I explain the context in which the usage (whose meaning is clarified clearly by Greybeard) is appropriate. I do not believe that we are here to make matters esoteric. We are here for a purpose - to help, not to create a holy of holies that is the preserve of the initiated. Where better should the questioner turn to for this combination of meaning and context?

Comment: Read Tim's comment. Basic research is _expected_ on ELU.

Answer (score 0):

**to cut** (verb) = to slice; to use a sharp edge to sever something "He cut the rope with a knife." In your example, a pair of scissors is implied.

**up** (emphatic adverb) = completely, fully. In *"He opened the box."* -he might only open the box by just a little - slightly. In *He opened the box up"*, he fully opens the box - perhaps he takes the lid off.

**Suit** (clothing) - usually, a matching jacket and trousers or jacket and skirt.

Comment: Answering this diminishes the propriety of the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what do you mean by propriety of the site?

Comment: ELL, our sister site, was set up to help with more basic questions ... though even there, I think that they expect some basic research (like looking up and quoting definitions of 'suit', 'cut up'). In the introduction to the site, it is made clear that basic questions, and especially questions lacking reasonable research, are inappropriate on ELU. Answering them (in 'answers') wrongly encourages further such inappropriate questions. _There are many other sites which are aimed at answering more basic questions, some no doubt not having ELU's reasonable research requirement.

Comment: I knew the meaning of suit and cut up and I had done research. But it was very strange for me that someone cuts up many suits carefully!! So I thought that I have misunderstood the sentence and "suit" and "cut up" might have another meaning which I couldn't find by research or maybe the whole sentence has a different meaning other  than the apparent one.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi - you misquoted. No-one said she cut them up carefully. Calmly, as in not in temper, and deliberately as in meaning every cut.